# How can I ensure that certain method and fields are visible only to a child class?

Tags: c#, visibility

I'm not sure if this is possible but I want to be able to have fields/method of a base class to be visible to the parent.

Say for example I have a class:

```
public class ExampleFile
{
    private Stream _stream;
    private long _baseoffset;

    public ExampleFile(Stream input)
    {
        _stream = input;
        _baseoffset = input.Position;
    }

    public void SeekTo(long offset)
    {
        _stream.Seek(offset + _baseoffset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }
}
```

And I then use that class as a base for another class:

```
public class ExampleClass : ExampleFile
{
    public ExampleClass(Stream input)
        : base(input)
    {
    }

    public byte[] GetSomething()
    {
        byte[] id = new byte[5];
        SeekTo(2);
        base._stream.Read(id, 0, 5);
        return id;
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can make the fields/methods of `ExampleFile` only visible to `ExampleClass`?

Comment: Not while still allowing `ExampleClass` to be inherited.

Comment: @John I read your comment about a dozen times before I finally understood what you meant, good point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`protected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) modifier instead of public/private on the fields/properties/methods you want exposed to child classes.

```
public class ExampleFile
{
    protected Stream _stream;  // no longer private, so the inherited
    protected long _baseoffset; //classes can access them

    public ExampleFile(Stream input)
    {
        _stream = input;
        _baseoffset = input.Position;
    }

    public void SeekTo(long offset)
    {
        _stream.Seek(offset + _baseoffset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }
}
```

Comment: -1: although accepted as the answer, it doesn't actually answer the question. The question was how to expose members _only_ to the first derived class. There is no way to do that unless you make that class `sealed`, preventing it from being inherited.

Comment: @John I understand your point John, and your right, but I think your reading to far into the question. `I want to be able to have fields/method of a base class to be visible to the parent.` says nothing about only the first derived class.

Comment: Rather than make the backing variables (private) into protected, it's generally best practice to make protected property accessors instead.

Comment: OP said, "Is there any way I can make the fields/methods of ExampleFile only visible to `ExampleClass`?"

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by base class? The base class is supposed be the parent in your case! If you want a member of a class to be accessible to one of its descendants, use the `protected` modifier. If you want a member of the child class to be accessible to its parent, do so through a *getter*.